# openmoney query SDK query SDK for production

Tags: payment-gateway, payment, currency

`const sdk = require('api')('@bank-open/v1#1mld74kq6w4cej');`

if this is for sandbox what is for production in OPENMONEY payment gateway

```
sdk.auth(token)
        let result = await sdk.generateToken({
            amount: parseFloat(order_amount),
            udf: {
                "membershipCustomer_id": membershipCustomer_id,
                "customer_id": customer_id,
                "order_id": order_id,
            },
            contact_number: customerData?.mobile ? customerData?.mobile : "9999999999",
            email_id: customerData?.email ? customerData?.email : "aaa@gmail.com",
            currency: currencyFormat ? currencyFormat.toString() : 'INR',
            mtx: transactionId.toString(),
        })
```

Comment: Please indicate a programming language to interpret the code presented: the conventional way is to tag accordingly.